# Adding coordinates of an object to a map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I have a data frame of a ship names and their latitudes and longitudes:

```
d <- data.frame(
   object = c("TIGAN", "KETLIN", "VOSKHOD"),
   long = c(59.38163, 59.42280, 59.90143),
   lat = c(22.21518, 22.29112, 27.58729))
 class(d)
```

I want to plot these points on a map. I have created a map from shp object.

```
 library(sf)
 map <- read_sf("C:\\Julia\\Estonia_shapefile\\ee_10km.shp")
 class(map)
 print(map)
 plot(map)
 library(ggplot2)
   ggplot(st_union(map, by_feature = FALSE) %>% st_sf()) + geom_sf()
```

How can I add this objects on a map?

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
d <- data.frame(
  object = c("TIGAN", "KETLIN", "VOSKHOD"),
  long = c(59.38163, 59.42280, 59.90143),
  lat = c(22.21518, 22.29112, 27.58729)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

map <- read_sf("C:\\Julia\\Estonia_shapefile\\ee_10km.shp")

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = d, aes(color = object)) +
  geom_sf(data = map) +
  coord_sf()
```

Comment: Simple and straightforward, nice. FYI, dplyr is not required here, you can replace `%>%` with `|>` (R-4) and it will work just as nicely

Comment: Good point, I never got in the habit of the base R pipe, but I should.

Comment: The only reason I say that is that you're bring in dplyr here _solely_ for the use of `magrittr::\`%>%\``, nothing else. I think for that reason and because the native `|>` pipe is a perfect replacement, there's no reason to add "bloat" to an answer. There are a few key ways that the two pipes do differ, though, so I'm not going base-R-elite or anti-dplyr, just "as few addons as needed". Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, your point is valid.